# XSLT Correct usage of child::* , Difference between using xsl:for-each and xsl:template in this scenario

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I tried creating XSL transformation for the input xml of the below format.

With both `<xsl:for-each />`  and `<xsl:template />`

**XML 1:**

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title>charithram</title>
        <author>sarika</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>doublebell</title>
        <author>psudarsanan</author>
    </book>
</books>
```

**XSLT 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or

**XSLT 2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="books/book">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author" /></td>
      </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet
```

......

Now, if the XML is

**XML 2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book.child.1>
        <title>charithram</title>
        <author>sarika</author>
    </book.child.1>
    <book.child.2>
        <title>doublebell</title>
        <author>psudarsanan</author>
    </book.child.2>
</books>
```

I am able to accomplish the result with usage of `books/child::*`

**XSLT 3:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="books/child::*">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the difference between using `<xsl:for-each/>`  and applying template in the above scenario? I do not see any difference. [**XSLT 1 and XSLT 2**]
2. Please validate  if this is the correct usage.  [using   `<xsl:for-each select="books/child::*">`   to accomplish the result]  [**XSLT 3**]

Update:
I have removed my third question and will post in a different thread.

Comment: You really need to break this question down into one single question. Too many questions makes the answers you get too... unwieldy.

Comment: Sure, I will break the third question in a seperate thread. thanks

Comment: For (2) yes, that will work, but `books/child::*` can be shortened to `books/*` as `child::` is the default axis.

Comment: @MatthewGreen , I placed my third question in a seperate thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441874/xslt-appending-incremented-value-to-existing-attribute-value

Comment: @IanRoberts Thank you, I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In fact, you're right. `xsl:for-each` is a sort of "anonymous inline template". It's actually bad practice in many cases, since it tends to indicate that the stylesheet is being written procedurally rather than rule-driven... but it is occasionally the best way to express your logic. As with most programming languages, there's more than one way to solve most problems and it's up to the programmer to develop a sense of style to pick the best one.

2) As Ian Roberts said, "yes, that will work, but books/child::* can be shortened to books/* as child:: is the default axis". (He does deserve the credit for answering that one -- I was half-asleep and didn't get a Round Tuit.)

Comment: Thanks keshlam .How can i accept your answer for (1) as well as @IanRoberts anwer for (2) ? can you quote his reply or need I? 

I have to try putting the position() or  <xsl:number/>  inside the  <xsl:template /> to see if i get the expected output as in the case of putting position() inside the <xsl:for-each />. I will try it out and  accept soon.

Comment: Here you see why it's a good idea to split different questions in the first place. Create a new question for 2.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, you're right. Going forward, i will ensure i will stick to one question per thread. I don't think appropriate to break this thread as it is complete now.  However, I still have a question related to using position() on the two approaches, and i will post it in a seperate question.

Comment: I posted my query on position() usage in template vs for-each , as a different SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470578/xslt-1-0-using-position-in-xslfor-each-and-xsltemplate