# XSLT Appending incremented value to existing attribute value

Tags: xslt

For my input XML, I have written the XSLT , But  I cannot make the XSLT to  generate the `<mynewtag>`  correctly. Please help.

*XML input:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book.child.1>
        <title>charithram</title>
        <author>sarika</author>
    </book.child.1>
    <book.child.2>
        <title>doublebell</title>
        <author>psudarsanan</author>
    </book.child.2>
</books>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newbooks>
   <newbook>
      <mynewtag id="book1" />
      <title>charithram</title>
      <author>sarika</author>
   </newbook>
   <newbook>
      <mynewtag id="book2" />
      <title>doublebell</title>
      <author>psudarsanan</author>
   </newbook>
</newbooks>
```

XSLT that I tried: [I understand the syntax is incorrect for `<mynewtag>` ]. But I don't know to fix it to get the desired output.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <newbooks>
            <xsl:for-each select="books/child::*">
                <newbook>
                    <mynewtag id="book<xsl:number value='position()' format='1' />" /> 
                    <title>
                        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                    </title>

                    <author>
                        <xsl:value-of select="author" />
                    </author>
                </newbook>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </newbooks>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Trying in Online XSLT transformer , http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

I tried assigning the position to a variable, but still I face the same problem of not knowing how to append it with the attribute value `book` .

```
<xsl:variable name="cnt">
  <xsl:number value='position()' format='1' />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select = "$cnt" />
```

Note: If I remove the `<xsl:number value='position()' format='1' />` from XSL, then the syntax is correct, but then I won't be able to generate `book1`  `book2`  etc as `<mynewtag>` attribute values.

Please help.

**Added**: `<mynewtag>` is a required element. It is like any other XML element like `<title>` that is required in output. It is not an element just to hold the attribute `id`. Sorry if there is a confusion on this.

**Adding Solution here, from the answers obtained to summarize:**

```
<mynewtag>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:text>book</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number value='position()'/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</mynewtag>
```

or shortly:

```
<mynewtag id="book{position()}" />"
```

or

```
  <newbook> 
        <xsl:variable name="cnt">
          <xsl:number value='position()' format='1' />
        </xsl:variable>
            <mynewtag id="book{$cnt}" />
             ..........
```

Also the attribute value templates that IanRoberts mentioned.

Comment: Read up on [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)

Comment: Thank you @IanRoberts for providing reference on attribute value templates. Though michael.hor257k has answered my query completely, this extra reference helped me to look into it more. 

So I can achieve the result by a different way too . Thanks!
<mynewtag id="book{$cnt}" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place a tag inside another tag. Try either:

```
<mynewtag>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:text>book</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number value='position()'/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</mynewtag>
```

or shortly:

```
<mynewtag id="book{position()}" />"
```

---

**ADDED:**
Not directly related to your question, but I believe the id attribute should be applied to the parent `<newbook>` element, instead of creating an artificial child element to hold it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both the suggestion, and it works. Exactly what i was looking for, and IanRoberts reference on attribute value elements [your second suggestion] made me understand more on its usage. 

To your extra note on adding the id attribute to the <newbook> element, i understand what you are saying, but in my real scenario, the attribute name is not id, it is a href for custom purpose. The purpose of <mynewtag> element in this case is not to hold the id attribute, it has its own importance in the real context. Thanks , and I appreciate your help

Comment: It was not attribute value elements. I meant to say attribute value templates.