# XSLT 1.0 Using position() in <xsl:for-each> and <xsl:template>

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My understanding is that the usage of `<xsl:template />` and `<xsl:for-each>` almost serve the same purpose and `<xsl:for-each >` is a sort of *"anonymous inline template"*.

**Question:** However, considering the below scenario, i think using `<xsl:for-each>` is more appropriate. 
Please validate my understanding, or is there a way the output can be achieved through `<xsl:template>` as well?

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book.child.1>
        <title>charithram</title>
        <author>sarika</author>
    </book.child.1>
    <book.child.2>
        <title>doublebell</title>
        <author>psudarsanan</author>
    </book.child.2>
</books>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
   <book id="book1">
      <title>charithram</title>
      <author>sarika</author>
   </book>
   <book id="book2">
      <title>doublebell</title>
      <author>psudarsanan</author>
   </book>
</books>
```

**XSLT1 [using `<xsl:for-each >`]**   - This gives the expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
        <newbooks>
            <xsl:for-each select="books/*">
            <newbook id="book{position()}"> 
                <title><xsl:value-of select="title" /></title>
                <author> <xsl:value-of select="author" /></author>
            </newbook>
          </xsl:for-each>
           </newbooks>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT2 [using `<xsl:template >`]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />    
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <newbooks>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>    
     </newbooks>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="books/*" >
    <newbook id="book{position()}"> 
        <title><xsl:value-of select="title" /></title>
        <author> <xsl:value-of select="author" /></author>
    </newbook>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does not give the expected output, Instead, the output obtained is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <newbooks>
       <newbook id="book2">
          <title>charithram</title>
          <author>sarika</author>
       </newbook>
       <newbook id="book4">
          <title>doublebell</title>
          <author>psudarsanan</author>
       </newbook>
    </newbooks>
```

The only reason i can think of getting 2 and 4, could be the position of `id` node inside the context.
"The `position()` function returns the position of the context node in a selected set of nodes". As per this definition, it works in the case of `for-each` as the context is each `<book>` element. But why it is not applicable in the case of template?

I also tried with `<xsl:number>` , but cannot make it to work as expected

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
        <newbooks>
                  <xsl:apply-templates/>    
         </newbooks>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="books/*" >
        <newbook >
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:text>book</xsl:text><xsl:number/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="title" /></title>
            <author> <xsl:value-of select="author" /></author>
        </newbook>
     </xsl:template>
```

I am getting the output of book1, book1 [not incrementing]

**Please help.**

Note: I use XSLT to transform into output XML which has complete different set of tags compared to input XML, so I don't use a template to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your understanding of the differences is a bit faulty, but that is not the issue here, since your `<xsl:apply-templates />` essentially does the same as an `<xsl:for-each>`.

**But:** You have a major difference in the selectors you use in the two code snippets. Your first example uses `<xsl:for-each select="books/*">`, which creates a node set of cardinality two, numbered, unsurprisingly, 1 and 2. Your second code snippet uses `<xsl:apply-templates />`, which is a shorthand for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()">`, and that creates a node set of cardinality five(!), with nodes 1, 3, and 5 being text nodes (that happen to only contain whitespace), and nodes 2 and 4 being the ones you actually want to target.

Solution? Add your selector to the `apply-templates` element, as in `<xsl:apply-templates select="books/*" />`.

**EDIT** So, why is the node set in the second case that big? Because it picks up all child nodes of `books`, and the way XML works is that that includes not only elements – it also includes text nodes (you do want your `<title>` and `<author>` to have a text node child) – *including the text nodes that stem from your indenting,* which only contain things like end-of-line and spaces and/or tabs, collectively known as whitespace. Try the original second code on these input variations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book.child.1>
        <title>charithram</title>
        <author>sarika</author>
    </book.child.1>
    <book.child.2>
        <title>doublebell</title>
        <author>psudarsanan</author>
    </book.child.2>
</books>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books><book.child.1>
        <title>charithram</title>
        <author>sarika</author>
    </book.child.1>
    <book.child.2>
        <title>doublebell</title>
        <author>psudarsanan</author>
    </book.child.2>
</books>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books><book.child.1>
        <title>charithram</title>
        <author>sarika</author>
    </book.child.1><book.child.2>
        <title>doublebell</title>
        <author>psudarsanan</author>
    </book.child.2>
</books>
```

Also note that elements and text are not the only types of nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <!-- first book -->
    <book.child.1>
        <title>charithram</title>
        <author>sarika</author>
    </book.child.1>
    <!-- second book -->
    <book.child.2>
        <title>doublebell</title>
        <author>psudarsanan</author>
    </book.child.2>
</books>
```

If you had templates matching these (such as an `<xsl:template match='text()'>` or maybe something more specific), you’d find the corresponding output there. XSLT just defaults to ignoring unmatched nodes in apply-templates.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, I understand the issue, and tried out adding the selector to apply-templates, getting the expected output.  However, With respect to the cardinality, the for-each creates a node set of cardinality two. But I do not understand how <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"> creates a node set of cardinality five, and nodes 2 and 4 being the ones i am targetting. Can you please explain on that

Comment: Nice, I  understand how we got  the cardinality of five[can be any number based on varying the input], and i 
tried with the various input variations to see the different positions. Thanks for explaining 'how it works' rather than plain answer to the OP. Appreciated.